# Why is there XSS attack from own IP?

Tags: wordpress, xss

On my WordPress website, Wordfence gave me the following alert:

```
12.34.56.78 (Germany)
Blocked for XSS: Cross Site Scripting in POST body: strings=<img class="wp-image-5296 alignright" src="https://www.my-website.com/wp-content/upload\xea
```

*To my surprise, the IP address is mine!*

I edited some WordPress pages when I received this alert.

How come that I am the source of an XSS attack?

What could be the source?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That's not easy to tell without taking a close look at the whole setup. But XSS is a generic term for a huge group a attacks. It could be malicious code injected to your site with the aim to transparent confidential information of your WordPress to a foreign site. So a hacker might have injected malicious code that is executed by you when you are logged in.

Comment: Try to add add your IP in wishlist, and check